# different jdk versions leads to ambiguity

Tags: android, windows-8.1, java

My android studio runs on Java 1.8 (64) and The project which I am doing right now works only on Java 1.7 (32). I have installed both but I think it only takes 1.8 so that my project does not work when android studio works. Please give me a suggestion so that the both run simultaneously without hassle.

Comment: JAVA_HOME leads to 1.8 while path leads to 1.7 but my project does not work this way.

Comment: When you say path are you saying your Build Path?

Comment: yeah Path environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Have you actualized your JAVA_HOME variable with the new Java version 1.8?

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't see your response.

Comment: Yeah because Android studio requires JAVA_HOME and it needs to be java 1.8 ... IF i unistall 1.8 then my project runs perfectly fine but android studio does not

Comment: What program do you use to run your project?

Comment: And... can you put both versions of Java in the JAVA_HOME variable? I think the incompatibility it's because you have the version 1.8 of Java in 64 bits and the 1.7 version in 32 bits. Or try to dowload 1.8 (32 bits) version of Java in Linux and run your project there, and see if it works by this way. I expect it will works.